# I want to know why should I not use AND operator in this case?

Tags: sql

So I am supposed to find the first_name and email of patrons who lost their library card.

The correct solution to the scenario is:

```
SELECT first_name, email 
FROM patrons 
WHERE library_id = "MCL1001" 
   OR library_id = "MCL1100" 
   OR library_id = "MCL1011";
```

I want to know why cannot we use AND here, I am a beginner trying to learn SQL and I am having hard time to visualize why AND in this case is a wrong option

My answer is:

```
SELECT first_name, email 
FROM patrons 
WHERE library_id = "MCL1001" 
  AND library_id = "MCL1100" 
  AND library_id = "MCL1011";
```

Please help and thanks in advance.

Comment: Please how your data and expected result from the query .which database are you using @Shubham Mishra

Comment: Hey, thanks for the edit.Appreciate that. Will keep that in mind next time :)

Comment: @Rohit Poudel ...I am using SQL playground at treehouse.com

Comment: @Shubham Mishra  single  rows of data cannot have all three id but it selects the data when one of the three condition is met not all condtions at a time

Comment: @ShubhamMishra upvote the answers that helped you so that they can help another person

Comment: @ShubhamMishra: It's mainly problem of spoken language. You say `give me apples AND oranges`, but each individual fruit is either an apple OR an orange, not both :-)

Answer (score 0):

Think about the conditions for one single row at a time. With `AND` the condition says:

- Find a row with `id = "MCL1001"` AND (at the same time) with `library_id = "MCL1100"`.

This will never be true, because for a single row, library_id will never have two different values.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the help. Now I have more clarity on AND and OR.

Answer (score 0):

If you use AND, the result will just be TRUE if `library_id` is equal, at the same time, to your three values, what is impossible because `library_id` can store only one value. Search about [Boolean algebra](https://medium.com/i-math/intro-to-truth-tables-boolean-algebra).

An AND operation will result TRUE only when all the sentences are TRUE. An OR operation, instead, will result TRUE when at least one sentence is TRUE.

Answer (score 0):

AND is when you need to match all the conditions, OR when matching any of the condition is enough. So if you have 3 rows with 3 IDs AND will return if all 3 are matched (or lost in your case). Even if one is lost AND will not show the row while OR will.

Comment: Thanks, Srihari . Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

These operators coming from [Boolean algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra)

There are three [basic operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations) there:

- AND ([conjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_conjunction)), denoted x∧y (sometimes x AND y or Kxy), satisfies
  x∧y = 1 if x = y = 1 and x∧y = 0 otherwise.
- OR ([disjunction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_disjunction)), denoted
  x∨y (sometimes x OR y or Axy), satisfies x∨y = 0 if x = y = 0 and x∨y
  = 1 otherwise.
- NOT ([negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation)), denoted ¬x (sometimes NOT x, Nx or !x), satisfies ¬x = 0 if x = 1 and ¬x = 1 if x = 0.

You will find very detailed description of these operations in the links above.
**I can't belive you haven't learned this in school.**

---

`library_id = "MCL1001" AND library_id = "MCL1100"` condition means, that each row must satisfy this condition to be selected by the query.
One column value cannot be both `MCL1001` and `MCL1100`, and this condition is always false, so the query neger gives any row.

---

In this condition: `library_id = "MCL1001" OR library_id = "MCL1001"` the column  value can be `MCL1001` OR `MCL1001`, so the query pick a row that contain first value, and another row that contains the second value.

Comment: I know this but had trouble applying it.Anyways thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

When you execute at this query :

```
SELECT first_name, email 
FROM patrons 
WHERE library_id = "MCL1001" 
  AND library_id = "MCL1100" 
  AND library_id = "MCL1011";
```

It will go into table patrons and look for a row where `library_id = "MCL1001"` and also check the same row if `library_id = "MCL1100"`  and also check the same row  if `library_id = "MCL1011";`. Such a row in your database will never exist.

but when you execute :

```
SELECT first_name, email 
FROM patrons 
WHERE library_id = "MCL1001" 
   OR library_id = "MCL1100" 
   OR library_id = "MCL1011";
```

It will go to your table patrons and check any row where `library_id = "MCL1001"`  return that ,continue check any row where `library_id = "MCL1100"` return it ,continue  and 
check any row where `library_id = "MCL1011";` and return it. So you can get all the three rows.

Because the AND condition checks if all conditions are satisfied in each row , While the OR condition only checks for one correct condition and continues,

Your query was wrong to write.